# Choose where to install bitcoin-qt (linux)

Tags: bitcoin-core, linux

I don't have much space on my / (~12GB) so I would like to install bitcoin-qt to some other drive with free space (since the data files will take around 10GB after synchronization). How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run bitcoin with the flag

```
-datadir=<path to a directory>
```

Comment: and this is gonna **move** the data files to desired path?

Comment: No it will redownload if it's not already there. So you may want to move whatever you have to that path first. (while bitcoin-qt is NOT running).